# Nuxt3: Strapi Content not Updating on Production Server

Tags: caching, nuxt.js, apollo, strapi, nuxt3

I am currently working on a site (mbmobilesauna.de) with Nuxt3 in the frontend. My backend is Strapi CMS. Both sites are actively running actually well in prod and dev. Side note: I've only been involved with Nuxt for a few months.

**My problem:**

I maintain the content of my site (https://mbmobilesauna.de) with Strapi. If I now change content in Strapi, this should then also update the website. This works so far but **ONLY** on **localhost** and not on the actual production URL.

My two sites (frontend, backend) are hosted at a service provider that uses Cloudflare. This service provider has assured me 100% that the problem is not with Cloudflare. Cloudflare caches the page only 4 hours and after the 4 hours the content should change but unfortunately this is not the case.

For my frontend project I have a Dockerfile and a Deployment.yaml which automatically publish my project as soon as I commit something new. To exclude that this is the reason, I have also tested all locally in a Docker container. Here the desired behavior is there. As soon as I change something in Strapi, the page that is in the Docker container is updated directly.

To exclude the possibility that this is a bug in Strapi, I used the Strapi prodction URL in the local development environment.

As already mentioned, everything works as it should perfectly on localhost. But as soon as the page is **in production**, the **content** **is no longer updated** unless I manually make a release in the frontend pipeline. (This behavior is not desired)

**What I tried:**

- Try another hosting provider (Netlify, Firebase) - Here I have the same problem again in Production.
- Try different browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Opera) - Again the same problem
- Deactivate cache - Again the same problem
- Clear cache completely - Again the same problem

**How do I get my data out of Strapi:**
nuxt.config.ts

```
  apollo: {
    clients: {
      default: {
        httpEndpoint: `https://STRAPI_PROD_URL/graphql`,
        browserHttpEndpoint: `https://STRAPI_PROD_URL/graphql`,
        connectToDevTools: false,
      },
    },
  },
```

index.vue

```
import gql from "graphql-tag";

const GET_HOMEPAGE = gql`
  query Homepage {
    homepage {
      data {
        id
        attributes {
          body {
            __typename
            ... on ComponentContentTypeCtLandingSection {
              id
              title
              landingDesc: description
              images {
                data {
                  id
                  attributes {
                    url
                    alternativeText
                  }
                }
              }
              link {
                id
                label
                url
                style
                unterseiten {
                  data {
                    id
                    attributes {
                      title
                      slug
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;

const { data }: any = await useAsyncQuery({
  query: GET_HOMEPAGE,
  cache: false
});
```

I use for my requests NuxtApollo (https://apollo.nuxtjs.org/) and GraphQL**

I have provided my complete repo here for more details:**
https://github.com/Nirwana3301/SaunaFrontendNuxtStackoverflow

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I have not found out what was wrong with Apollo. In any case, I have now used the Nuxt/Strapi module.

Here is my code:

```
import homepageQuery from "../queries/Homepage.gql";

const graphql = useStrapiGraphQL()

const { data } : any = await graphql(homepageQuery)
```

Answer (score 0):

So the problem I have is 100% with Apollo. I used the Nuxt/Strapi module (https://strapi.nuxtjs.org/) to get my data out of Strapi and everything worked perfectly the way I wanted it to.

I would still like to find out why it doesn't work with Apollo.

When I have found a solution I will close the issue. I will then post the solution here